# "Squishing" an array of nested objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

is there any easy way to "squish down", for lack of a better word, an array of nested object that share key-value pairs?

Essentially I have the following object that represents a parent child relationship (projects and project tasks). In my case I have four tasks total returning from my query but my API will always return the parent project with each child task.

```
obj = [
  {
    id: "213",
    customer: "11",
    project: "Second Project",
    tasks: {
      internalid: "8",
      id: "2",
      title: "Testing",
    },
  },
  {
    id: "213",
    customer: "11",
    project: "Second Project",
    tasks: {
      internalid: "9",
      id: "3",
      title: "Close",
    },
  },
  {
    id: "10",
    customer: "318",
    project: "Chicago Auto Show",
    tasks: {
      internalid: "2",
      id: "1",
      title: "Test task 1",
    },
  },
  {
    id: "10",
    customer: "318",
    project: "Chicago Auto Show",
    tasks: {
      internalid: "6",
      id: "2",
      title: "Task 2.5",
    },
  },
];
```

What I'm trying to end up with is something like this:

```
obj = [
  {
    id: "213",
    customer: "11",
    project: "Second Project",
    tasks: [
      {
        internalid: "8",
        id: "2",
        title: "Testing",
      },
      {
        internalid: "9",
        id: "3",
        title: "Close",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "10",
    customer: "318",
    project: "Chicago Auto Show",
    tasks: [
      {
        internalid: "2",
        id: "1",
        title: "Test task 1",
      },
      {
        internalid: "6",
        id: "2",
        title: "Task 2.5",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Is there any nice function that will allow me to do this? Also I can format my input really however makes this type of organization easiest with parent-child "smooshing".

Comment: There's always a way. What have you tried so far? Also, if the customer `id` is a match, are the customer number and project also guaranteed to match, or would your code that does the squishing need to ensure that all three match before considering it the same (and squishable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to group your data by `id` (or more fields if needed):

```js
let obj = [
  {
    id: "213",
    customer: "11",
    project: "Second Project",
    tasks: {
      internalid: "8",
      id: "2",
      title: "Testing",
    },
  },
  {
    id: "213",
    customer: "11",
    project: "Second Project",
    tasks: {
      internalid: "9",
      id: "3",
      title: "Close",
    },
  },
  {
    id: "10",
    customer: "318",
    project: "Chicago Auto Show",
    tasks: {
      internalid: "2",
      id: "1",
      title: "Test task 1",
    },
  },
  {
    id: "10",
    customer: "318",
    project: "Chicago Auto Show",
    tasks: {
      internalid: "6",
      id: "2",
      title: "Task 2.5",
    },
  },
];

let result = obj.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    let match = acc.find(x => x.id === curr.id); //+ customer, project if needed
    if(!match){
        match = { ...curr, tasks: [ ] };
        acc.push(match);
    }
    match.tasks.push(curr.tasks);
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also could use foreach:

```
const obj = [
  {
    id: "213",
    customer: "11",
    project: "Second Project",
    tasks: {
      internalid: "8",
      id: "2",
      title: "Testing",
    },
  },
  {
    id: "213",
    customer: "11",
    project: "Second Project",
    tasks: {
      internalid: "9",
      id: "3",
      title: "Close",
    },
  },
  {
    id: "10",
    customer: "318",
    project: "Chicago Auto Show",
    tasks: {
      internalid: "2",
      id: "1",
      title: "Test task 1",
    },
  },
  {
    id: "10",
    customer: "318",
    project: "Chicago Auto Show",
    tasks: {
      internalid: "6",
      id: "2",
      title: "Task 2.5",
    },
  }
];


function mergeProp(collection, key) {
    const result = {};
    collection.forEach(obj => {
        result[obj.id] = result[obj.id] ? {...obj, [key]:[...result[obj.id][key], obj[key]]} :  result[obj.id] = {...obj, [key]: [obj[key]]}
    });
    return Object.values(result);
}

console.log(mergeProp(obj, 'tasks'))
```